# Where does Android.Graphics.Camera set its X,Y, and Z axis when canvas is set to a bitmap?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to get a bitmap and manipulate it in the following way:[image]

I have created an empty bitmap, on this bitmap, I drew what I needed. Now I need to distorted in a way similar to this because I will then be drawing the whole thing ontop of another bitmap. Think of it as applying a texture to a box. The box simply being a picture of a box. The way that I see myself doing this is creating bitmaps off the main bitmap and drawing them onto the final bitmap through a matrix modified by Graphics.Camera.getMatrix().
I already have this working, but my problem is understanding just exactly how to manipulate the camera. I don't know where the camera creates its X Y and Z axis within the matrix. Or where does the matrix get applied. Or just how it all comes together.

When drawing on canvas set to view, I know I can rotate the canvas and draw from there to create a straight diagonal line, for example in a game engine to draw a projectile acting on two vectors. And I know when working on OpenGL, there is a state machine approach and I can imagine where the matrix is in 3D space. But I just don't understand how Camera, Matrix, and bitmap all relate.

From what I've looked up, I managed to set up the basic solution to this but havent been able to understand just exactly how to tweak this in order to get the right rotations. I have read the documentation but it doesn't really explain the relationship between Camera, Matrix, and canvas beyond the fact that Camera modifies a matrix and then canvas can draw something based on that matrix.

Can anyone explain how I would go about doing what I have in the picture? I already know that I'll be creating a bitmap from region in original bitmap. Then combining the two, to create what is on the right column , and then rotating the canvas/bitmap and getting another bitmap from green section and repeat the whole thing again.

Thanks

Comment: hi..i have similar problem...have you find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Camera is just a utility class that generates a Matrix you can use on Canvas. The generated Matrix contains the appropriate transform. You said it yourself:

> it doesn't really explain the relationship between Camera, Matrix, and
>   canvas beyond the fact that Camera modifies a matrix and then canvas
>   can draw something based on that matrix.

That's all there is to it really :)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm just kinda stuck. How can I make it so the camera has its origin at a specific point in the bitmap? Do I call a translation on the camera, then rotate? or call the camera rotation, and then translate or concatenate on the generated matrix?